# how do I forward by hostname to different web hosts behind a firewall --mod_proxy?

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I need a quick solution that allows me to host multiple web servers behind my firewall. They are on different computers, so I can't use apache virtual hosting. I also don't want to use different non-standard ports for each machine.

The problem is my router can only forward port 443 to one machine. I thought the best solution would be to use reverse proxy or proxy forwarding, but I have been having problems understanding how to set this up.

- I am assuming that I can port forward all 443 traffic to one of the
  servers and make that the proxy server.
- All servers accept htmls
  traffic only.
- I am using DDNS and all the servers resolve to the same
  WAN IP address.

Setup:

- server1.domain.com = proxy and wiki server
- server2.domain.com = documentation server
- server3.domain.com = owncloud server

I tried putting the following in `/etc/apache2/conf-available/proxy-pass.conf` on server1:

```
SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyPass "/directory"  "https://server2.domain.com/directory" 
ProxyPass "/owncloud"  "https://server3.domain.com/owncloud"
```

This works but it's not what I am looking for.

I need to direct all traffic to the server designated by the incoming URL domain name regardless of the directory because I have a lot of subdirectories after the base URL.

Something like:

```
ProxyPass "https://server2.domain.com"  "https://server2.domain.com" 
ProxyPass "https://server3.domain.com"  "https://server3.domain.com"
```

Should I be looking to another solution, such as `pound`, or is there a way of doing this with apache. I figured I have apache installed, so use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> They are on different computers, so I can't use apache virtual hosting

Actually that's is exactly what you need to do ;)

The manual is not explicit about it, but you reverse proxy everything for a specific host by making `/` , the root URL, the target for the ProxyPass directive in a virtual host entry:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName host.example.com
  ProxyPass / http://internalserver.example.net/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://internalserver.example.net/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName host2.example.com
  ProxyPass / http://other-internalserver.example.net/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://other-internalserver.example.net/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: ah... ok... so can I make one file such as `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/proxy.conf` for all of these directives?

Comment: Yes you can. (Or you can follow the Ubuntu convention and create a file for each individual VirtualHost `/etc/apache2/sites-available/host.example.com.conf` and then run `sudo a2ensite host.example.com.conf` and restart Apache.)

Comment: That did it.  I used a separate file since all the virtual hosts were spread out.  It seemed to make sense to me organizationally.

Comment: that is spread out over different servers.